# Path Integral on Einstein Cartan Manifold

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, differential-geometry, path-integral, dirac-equation

In condensed matter, crystal with disclination and dislocation has both curvature and torsion.
I am looking for a reference in which path integral quantization of Dirac equation on manifold with curvature and torsion was discussed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the name "Einstein-Cartan manifold" but if it is common usage, surely it wouldn't simply mean a manifold with nonzero torsion, surely it would be a manifold arising from the EC theory itself?